# Teleop and Network disconnections

Tags: ros, teleop, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I apologise if I've missed this on the way through, but is there a standard or conventional method for dealing with disconnections between the network and a tele-operator ?

My platform was chosen for it's off-road ability, so when I had a brief wifi hiccup the robot had climbed a mound of papers, mounted a nearby Pioneer 3 and had paused to contemplate the location of the nearest small child before I could hit the physical stop button.

I've contemplated sending a simple keep-alive message every 500ms or so, but it doesn't look like other people are doing this. How do people ensure they are in control of their robot in teleop ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27869/teleop-and-network-disconnections/) by [Tim S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1681/tim-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure there is a established standard best practice for ROS, but I´ve had good success with sending [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) messages at a fixed rate (say 10Hz) during teleop and stopping the robot as soon as no message has been received for a parametrizable time (say 300ms). An example of this scheme was implemented directly on the Arduino microcontroller of [this robot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zcr5IVYHN4) and it works well so far.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tim S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1681/tim-s/) on 2012-02-17**:
Thanks, that looks like the go, It looks like the joy node has an autorepeat_rate parameter which will work nicely. Until the device is a little more tested I think I'll use a deadman switch, and the  autorepeat will make it easy to keep track of my deadman button. Cheers

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-18**:
Some kind of fail-safe heartbeat is essential when controlling a robot remotely. If communication is lost, the robot should do an immediate emergency stop.